# Golang fuzzing fixed-length strings

Tags: go, fuzzing

I'm looking for a efficient way to test fixed-length strings via fuzzing (so that only the content of the string is variable, not the length).
My first idea was to use arrays for this like

```
f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, stringUnderTest [8]byte))
```

Sadly this doesn't work, as arrays are not supported (https://go.dev/security/fuzz/).
Is there any way to tell the fuzzer: "This string is only 8 digits"?